# Prevent form submitting if validation fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone help spot where I'm going wrong with my code, I cannot prevent the form from submitting even if form fields are invalid, I have been at this all day and have tried numerous ways but no luck.

```
 [Display(Name = "Amount to convert")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " is required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = " requires numbers only")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = " must be more than 1")] 





$(function() {
       // $("#frmWeightsMeasures").validate();
        $("#frmWeightsMeasures").submit(function(event) {
           // var isvalidate = $("#frmWeightsMeasures").valid();
           // if (isvalidate) {
                event.preventDefault();
           // }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: true,
                url: form.attr("action"),
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                error: searchFailed,
                success: function(weightsData) {
                    $("#DisplayConversion").html(weightsData.DisplayConversion);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function searchFailed(xhr, errorType, exception) {
        var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
        $("#DisplayConversion").html("Sorry, there was a problem with the search.");
    }
```

I have added the working code below, hopefully it will help someone in the future, moto of the story, when modify your code, watch what you delete.

```
$(function() {
            $("#frmWeightsMeasures").validate();
            $("#frmWeightsMeasures").submit(function(event) {
                var isvalidate = $("#frmWeightsMeasures").valid();
                if (isvalidate) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var form = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: true,
                        url: form.attr("action"),
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: searchFailed,
                        success: function(weightsData) {
                            $("#DisplayConversion").html(weightsData.DisplayConversion);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        function searchFailed(xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
            $("#DisplayConversion").html("Sorry, there was a problem with the search.");
        }
```

Comment: if you remove `[Required]`, does it return the correct error?

Comment: Hi andreister, no I then get the default mvc error Amount to convert is required, instead of just ' is required'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually referencing the form which is why it's saying it's undefined. you'll need to put the following before your ajax call:

> var form = $(this);

Also, for validation:

`return $(form).valid()` will prevent the form submitting if invalid

Comment: I have spent that long trying to sort this out, and tried different ways, I did not realise until about 2 minutes ago I deleted this line of code:  var form = $(this); added it back and now works ok. Sorry, spent to long looking at the computer

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a event.preventdefault() and event.stopPropagation()

the preventdefault alone will still allow the error to bubble up, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Hi E.J Brennan, still get same error, 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'form' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is returning false in case of error, instead of .preventDefault();